# Split string into array as in the following format

Tags: java, regex, string, split

The following is the input format

```
str = "New 25 \nMy Val 50 \nOld 25 ";
String[] words = str.trim().split("\\s+");
for(int i = 0; i <words.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
New
25
My 
Val
50
Old
25
```

But my expectation is :

```
New
25
My Val
50
Old
25
```

How can i achieve this in java using regex

Comment: Your output/desired output doesn't match the input you provided.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. The input is "My Val 25 \nNew 50 \nOld 25 "

Comment: @KarthikSankar edit your question with proper input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
String str = "My phone 25\nValet 50\niPod 25";

String lines[] = str.split("\\r?\\n");

for(String line : lines){
    int index=line.trim().lastIndexOf(" ");
    String str1 = line.substring(0,index);
    System.out.println(str1);
    String str2 = line.substring(index+1);
    System.out.println(str2);
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Can u just explain "\\r?\\n"

Comment: @KarthikSankar this are _newline_ characters for UNIX and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose your code str like this   str = "My Val 25 New 50 Old 25";
the solution for your answer as the follow

```
str = "My Val 25 New 50 Old 25";
String[] words = str.trim().split("\\s+");
for(int i = 0; i <words.length; i++) {
       if(i == 0 ){
         System.out.print(words[i]+" ");
       }
       else{
               System.out.println(words[i]);
       }
}
```

Comment: If i had str like this "New 25 \nMy Val 50 \nOld 25 " your code wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is so much ambiguous, but still trying to understand your problem and answering. Hope it will help you!!

> I think your string is composed of some `key` and numeric `value` corresponding to it.

If it is so then you can surely get the required output by splitting the string at all spaces coming before a number.

`[ ](?=\d)` will capture the space before any number.

```
str = "My phone 25\nValet 50\niPod 25";
String[] words = str.trim().split("[ ](?=\\d)");  // you need to escape '\' using extra '\'
for(int i = 0; i <words.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

Output will be:

```
My phone
25
Valet
50
iPod
25
```

Comment: Can u explain briefly "[ ](?=\d)"

Comment: `[ ]` is used for matching exactly one space, while `(?=\d)` is a positive lookahead for checking number. In whole, it will check for those spaces coming before any digit.

Comment: if i have to check space before two digit number. then how ca i check

Comment: `[ ](?=\d{2}\b)` this will help you to get space before 2 digit no.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure regex based `split` that doesn't require any code level post-processing:

```
String str = "New 25 \nMy Val 50 \nOld 25";
String[] words = str.trim().split("\\R+|\\h+(?=\\d{2})");
for(int i = 0; i <words.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

This regex splits on:

- `\\R+` - Matches one or more of any newline character
- `|` - OR
- `\\h+(?=\\d{2})` - Matches one or more of any horizontal whitespace that has 2 digits on next position.

**Output:**

```
New
25 
My Val
50 
Old
25
```

Comment: i want to check any horizontal whitespace that has two digit next. is it possible

Comment: Yes indeed, you can use `\\h+(?=\\d{2})` or see updated answer.